# Can't figure out how to build Firefox for Android

Tags: android, firefox, build, fennec

I'm trying to build Firefox for Android (Fennec) as close as possible to the release one would download from the Google Play Store.
I've searched for a guide and found that most resources link to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_for_Android_build
which supposedly has moved to https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/contributor/geckoview-quick-start

No particular step of this guide failed me, but at the end the only artifacts built are
`geckoview_example-withGeckoBinaries-debug-androidTest.apk` and
`geckoview_example-withGeckoBinaries-debug.apk` neither of which I'm looking for.
The commands used are as per the guide:

```
./mach bootstrap
./mach build
```

At the bootstrap step "Firefox for Android Artifact Mode" was chosen.
Am I missing something? Or is there a better guide actually focused on building Fennec, not GeckoView?

Answer (score 0):

Fennec implementation removed by Mozilla team in favor of Fenix. You can find on github/mercurial latest version with fennec(68) clone it and build.